# Efficiency on array iteration

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Consider a 2-d array n by n of the form
`array1 ={ {x11,x12,x13,...,x1n},{x21,x22,x23,...,x2n},{xn1,xn2,xn3,...,xnn}}`.
I want to expand every point in this array in terms of a 2-d Gaussian distribution.

The first step is to create an array which contains the normalization factors for the Gaussian distribution. This results is also a 2d array of the same form as the previous one this we'll name `array2`.

With the two arrays formed the main idea is to iterate through `array1` and for each element`[x,y]` in `array1` we sum over the multiple of element`[x,y]` and element`[i,j]` in `array2`.
Below is my attempt, which works but its very slow due to the use of loops.

```
GaussianArray[set1_, set2_] := Module[{
    n = Dimensions[set1][[1]],
    k = Dimensions[set2][[1]],
    i, j, l, m, x, y, t, res
    },
   res = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
   t = Ceiling[k/2];
   Do[
    Do[
      If[x + l - t == 0, i = Mod[x + l - t, n] + n, 
       i = Mod[x + l - t, n]];
      If[y + m - t == 0, j = Mod[y + m - t, n] + n, 
       j = Mod[y + m - t, n]];
      If[0 == i, i = x + l - t, i];
      If[0 == j, j = y + m - t, j];
      res[[x, y]] = res[[x, y]] + set1[[i, j]]*set2[[l, m]];
      , {l, 1, k}, {m, 1, k}];
    , {x, 1, n}, {y, 1, n}];
   res
   ];
```

There are some conditional statements required in order to deal with boundaries and to ensure that the correct multiplication is performed. This approach does give the desired result but as previously mentioned is dreadfully slow. I look forward to hearing ideas on how to improve this code.

As per some comment suggestions here is a more concrete example.
Let
`array1 = {{a11, a12, a13, a14, a15}, {a21, a22, a23, a24, a25}, {a31, a32, a33, a34, a35}, {a41, a42, a43, a44, a45}, {a51, a52, a53, a54, a55}}`
and
`array2 = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {h, i, j}};`
using my suggested solution we can look at the first element of
`GaussianArray[array1,arra2]`
which is
`a51 b + a52 c + a15 d + a11 e + a12 f + a25 h + a21 i + a22 j + a a55`

This approach is extremely slow. Below are two plot of the timing for different sizes of the arrays.
[image: Timing of Gaussian array. Blue plot (TOP) shows the dependence on the size of array2 with array1 having a constant size 200x200. Red plot (BOTTOM) shows the dependence on the size of array1 with array2 having a constant size 3x3.]

Comment: You can simply use `i = Mod[x + l - t, n, 1];j = Mod[y + m - t, n, 1];`. But that won't help much because your algorithm has complexity $O(n^2 \, k^2)$. I have not understood what you actually want to accomplish (this smells pretty much like an X-Y-question), but I am quite sure that there ought to be a more efficient algorithm for that.

Comment: I suspect that there is an answer using `ListCorrelate`. I didn't reverse engineer your code, but when your `set2` is 2x2, then `GaussianArray[set1, set2]` is equivalent to `ListCorrelate[set2, set1, {1, 1}]`. With ListCorrelate you can specify your own functions to use in place of Times and Plus so I assume there is a path here.

Comment: @GiovanniBaez Could you give some example with timing to compare with improved version?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I added comments on the timings. lericr suggestions makes my problem trivial even with large array of 10000 x 10000 arrays.

Comment: @lericr I tried your suggestion and it works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @lericr in the comments. `ListCorrelate[]` solves the timing issue. The code above can be changed to

```
GaussianArrayUpdate[set1_, set2_] := Module[{
    n = Dimensions[set1][[1]],
    k = Dimensions[set2][[1]],
    t, res
    },
   t = Ceiling[k/2];
   res = ListCorrelate[set2, set1, {t, t}];
   ];
```

This produces the same output as my original suggestion but works extremely fast. The picture below show timing for GaussianArrayUpdate.Blue denotes the timing for array1 set at a constant 200x200 and array2 with a varied size. Red denotes the timing for array2 set at a constant 3x3 and array1 with a varied size.

[image]